# Prove: If $p$ is a prime and $p>2$, then $p | [(2+\sqrt{5})^p]-2^{p+1}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove: If $p$ is a prime and $p>2$, then $p | [(2+\sqrt{5})^p]-2^{p+1}$

Comment: @Ihf For $p=3\Rightarrow 3|60.013$

Comment: If it is true then it seems that it is related to Fibonacci's numbers...

Comment: @Ihr It is my mistake. $p|[(2+\sqrt{5})^p]-2^{p+1}$, where $[(2+\sqrt{5})^p]$ is the integer part of $(2+\sqrt{5})^p$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a roadmap:

- $(2+\sqrt{5})^n+(2-\sqrt{5})^n$ is an integer because the terms with $\sqrt 5$ cancel
- $\left|2-\sqrt{5}\right|<1$ and so $(2-\sqrt{5})^n \to 0$
- $(2+\sqrt{5})^n+(2-\sqrt{5})^n = \lfloor (2+\sqrt{5})^n \rfloor$ when $n$ is odd
- When $n$ is a prime, $n$ divides $n \choose k$ for $0 < k < n$.

Comment: @Ihf What would be $[(2+\sqrt{5})^n]$ when $n$ is even?

Comment: @display_error, $(2+\sqrt{5})^n+(2-\sqrt{5})^n = \lceil (2+\sqrt{5})^n \rceil$ when $n$ is even.